# Transform Orientation - two of them?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transforms

Can someone explain to me the difference between these two panels when using any of the transform tools? One says Orientation and the other Transform Orientations...

Just don't get it.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Transform Orientations* on the left are for the currently active tool only, it is saved independently for each tool gizmo in the toolbar like Move, Rotate, Scale or others.

[image]

The *Transform Orientations* on the center of the 3D View header are the global ones for the scene, used whenever invoking transform operators directly from hotkeys, rather than using the tools from the toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I think naming it like global/current tool will help to avoid confusion.

Comment: This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For suggestions and feature requests use https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect or https://blenderartists.org.